# Object set to solid but some parts are still showing up as wireframe

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I recently decided to try my hand at making a mask. I was able to follow along with a video but once it came to the proportional part, I realized I could no long follow considering my object(mask) was not entirely solid

[image: mesh in question.]

I feel as if I'm missing a small step or maybe along the way I just messed something up while following along with the videos.

Comment: It looks like there the faces are missing, so just the vertices and edges are there. If you wanted to fix it, you can select the vertices and edges that surround a face in editmode and press f for fill

Answer (score 1):

1) Install the 'Mesh:F2' add-on from user preferences.
[image: Image 1]
2) Go to edit mode and change the selection type to face select. Select your whole mesh by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create faces in empty spaces. After that, select the extra face and delete it.
[image: Image 2]